# MySQL Subquery Sum & Limit

Tags: mysql, sum, limit

What I am trying to do is grab the last 4 person_id's and sum them.  Here is my current MySQL query.  What I am ending up with is person_id 23 = 4.  When I change LIMIT to 7 I end up with person_id 23 = 6, and person_id 24 = 2.  What I need is

```
person_id 23 = 4
person_id 24 = 8
person_id 25 = 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(ms.value) AS value, ms.person_id
FROM
    (SELECT mst.value, mst.id, mst.person_id
    FROM match_statistic AS mst
    WHERE mst.person_id IN (23,24,25)
    ORDER BY mst.id ASC
    LIMIT 4) AS sub
INNER JOIN match_statistic AS ms ON sub.id = ms.id
GROUP BY ms.person_id


  match_statistic table
| id | person_id | value |
| 10 |    23     |   1   |
| 11 |    23     |   1   |
| 12 |    23     |   1   |
| 13 |    23     |   1   |
| 14 |    23     |   1   |
| 15 |    23     |   1   |
| 16 |    24     |   2   |
| 17 |    24     |   2   |
| 18 |    24     |   2   |
| 19 |    24     |   2   |
| 20 |    24     |   2   |
| 21 |    24     |   2   |
| 22 |    25     |   3   |
| 23 |    25     |   3   |
| 24 |    25     |   3   |
| 25 |    25     |   3   |
| 26 |    25     |   3   |
| 27 |    25     |   3   |
```

Comment: What if you need to do this for a large number of unspecified number or all people?  You may have a hard time using UNION for that.  When-ever you need to change the structure of the SQL to handle a different set of people [(1, 2, 3) .vs. (1, 2, 3, 4)], you might want to reconsider the solution. It's probably a good idea to understand more general approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. It's a little more general without having to know the number of groups in the list. The answer is in the result.  I just left some extra rows for you to see the behavior.  It's not meant to be the final solution.  Just a big push in the right direction.

Note that you could use window functions for this if the database had that support.

```
SELECT t1.id
     , SUM(t2.value)
     , t1.person_id
     , COUNT(t2.id) AS cnt
  FROM theTable AS t1
  LEFT JOIN theTable AS t2
    ON (t1.id) <= (t2.id)
   AND t1.person_id = t2.person_id
 GROUP BY t1.id
        , t1.person_id
HAVING cnt <= 4 AND t1.person_id IN (23, 24, 25)
 ORDER BY t1.person_id, cnt
 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this check this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46329/18)

```
SELECT SUM(ms.value) AS value, ms.person_id FROM (
SELECT a.id, a.person_id, a.value, count(*) as row_number 
FROM MATCH_STATS a
JOIN MATCH_STATS b ON a.person_id = b.person_id AND a.id <= b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.person_id, a.value
) ms  WHERE ms.person_id IN (23,24,25) and row_number < 5
GROUP BY ms.person_id
```

OR

For your current query Change your inner query to

```
SELECT mst.value, mst.id, mst.person_id
    FROM match_statistic AS mst
    WHERE mst.person_id IN (23)
    ORDER BY mst.id ASC
    LIMIT 4

UNION ALL
SELECT mst.value, mst.id, mst.person_id
    FROM match_statistic AS mst
    WHERE mst.person_id IN (24)
    ORDER BY mst.id ASC
    LIMIT 4

UNION ALL
SELECT mst.value, mst.id, mst.person_id
    FROM match_statistic AS mst
    WHERE mst.person_id IN (25)
    ORDER BY mst.id ASC
    LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Only change would be to use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the 1st query.  The only thing I had to change was  ) ms  WHERE ms.person_id IN (23,24,25) and row_number < 5 to ) ms  WHERE ms.person_id IN (23,24,25) and row_number <= 4.

Comment: Ok, the problem I have now is I added date to the table and I would rather order by that then id.  Problem is I tried to add Order BY a.date DESC, a.id DESC, however its not working.  Any Ideas.

Comment: try to change this from `a.id <= b.id` to `a.datecol <= b.datecol AND a.id <= b.id`

Comment: I did, but all that did was pull all the results and did not limit.